# DB2 measure execution time of triggers

Tags: triggers, db2

How can I best measure the execution time of triggers in DB2 for insert or update.
It is needed for some performance issues, some of them are behaving very slow.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK
 NO CASCADE BEFORE INSERT ON DAG
 REFERENCING NEW AS OBJ
 FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL 
 WHEN(
  xyz)
 )
 SIGNAL SQLSTATE xxx)
```

Comment: What kind of triggers? Usually they are mixed into the regular statement execution. Have you looked at db2batch?

Comment: Just updated the question. I think db2batch helps me here not a lot. I make an insert via the application and from db side a trigger will triggered for the insert.

Answer (score 1):

**For compiled triggers (that is, with `BEGIN ... END` body):**

```
 SELECT 
   T.TRIGNAME 
 , M.SECTION_NUMBER
 , M.STMT_EXEC_TIME
 , M.NUM_EXEC_WITH_METRICS
 -- Other M metrics
 , M.*
 , M.STMT_TEXT
FROM SYSCAT.TRIGGERS T
JOIN SYSCAT.TRIGDEP D 
  ON (D.TRIGSCHEMA, D.TRIGNAME) = (T.TRIGSCHEMA, T.TRIGNAME)
JOIN TABLE (MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT (NULL, NULL, NULL, -2)) M
  ON (M.PACKAGE_SCHEMA, M.PACKAGE_NAME) = (D.BSCHEMA, D.BNAME)
WHERE D.BTYPE = 'K'
  -- Or use whatever filter on your triggers
  AND (T.TABSCHEMA, T.TABNAME) = ('MYSCHEMA', 'MYTABLE')
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

**For inlined triggers (that is, with `BEGIN ATOMIC ... END` body):**

No way to get separate statistics for them. They are compiled and optimized with the corresponding statement fired them.

Comment: Hmm for the above trigger I do no get any results, is it why it has no BEGIN END block?

Comment: Yes. If your trigger uses a single statement and doesn't use whatever `BEGIN ... END`, then it becomes inlined (implicitly using BEGIN ATOMIC ... END) one.

Comment: From performance perspective, is it better to use inlined triggers or compiled?

Comment: Generally if you trigger logic is relatively simple and can be done as inlined block, it's better to user inlined ones. But there are exceptions, of course, especially when the optimizer chooses some non-optimal access plan for your original statement firing this trigger.